# Gulp jade compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, pug

I'm using [gulp-jade](https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade) and I'm getting this error with one of my templates:

```
557| 
558| 
> 559| 
560|     .tabs-wrap(ng-show="eventExists"): .contain-center
561| 
562|       #room-tabs-contain.contain-disable.contain: .contain-center

unexpected token "pipeless-text"
at Parser.parseExpr (/Users/dylan/project/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:254:15)
```

At first glance it appears this is an error in github.com/jadejs/jade.  It might be, but I am also using jade to server templates with express, and when going through the express router, the template complies just fine with no errors.

I tried being explicit about the jade instance that gets used by gulp:

```
gulpjade = require 'gulp-jade'
jade = require 'jade'
locals = {}
gulp.src "#{config.client}/**/*.jade"
  .pipe gulpjade(jade: jade, pretty: true, locals: locals)
  .pipe gulp.dest("#{config.build}")
```

Still, no luck.  Key question I am trying to figure out is:

- Why does this jade template render fine through express, but it errors out when going through `gulp-jade`

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1628)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was wrong. I actually wasn't successfully rendering the template with express.

The correct solution, and the errors that my templates were experiencing were due to the changes between jade 1.9 and 1.11

## Example 1

- commenting out the `.col-sm-3.text-right` div

#### bad

```
//- .col-sm-3.text-right
```

#### good

```
//-
  .col-sm-3.text-right
```

---

## Example 2

- the `img` element should be visible, the `.col-sm-3.text-right` div should be commented out

#### bad

```
img(src="/image-path/png", alt="someimage")
  //- .col-sm-3.text-right
```

#### good

```
img(src="/image-path/png", alt="someimage")
//- .col-sm-3.text-right
```